# How to add an sql function to a laravel eloquent model

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm wanting to create a laravel model with a computed column. I've seen how to do this once the data is downloaded however the computation I wish to do is expensive but accessible as a function in my sql. Essentially I'd like to append one more column to the query builder but I'm unsure how to go about it.

The query needs to be something like:

```
select *, my_function(ID) as my_value from my_table;
```

and I need to get an instance of the model in return (not a raw recordset).

I'm also hoping to avoid multiple queries.

Thanks.

Comment: you can store query results in redis and define a scheduled job to update cached results check link below

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527161/using-redis-to-cache-sql-result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query can be something like this:

```
User::select([
   'users.*',
   \DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) as year')
])->get()
```

Replace YEAR function with whatever function you want. should append to the results that column as well.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I'm after

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from musicvicious I ended up going with:

```
class User extends Model
{
...

    public function newQuery()
    {
        return parent::newQuery()->select('users.*', \DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) as year'));
    }

}
```

Now I can just fetch the models as normal.

```
User::all();
```